# check status of message using txtlocal api

Tags: php

this is the code for sending messages using txtlocal

```
$message = urlencode($message);
    $data = "username=".$username."&hash=".$hash."&message=".$message."&sender=".$sender."&numbers=".$numbers."&test=".$test;
    $ch = curl_init('http://api.txtlocal.com/send/?');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // This is the result from the API
    echo $result;
    curl_close($ch);
```

but how can i check for some error. im using

```
echo $result;
```

to print the output result

and it gives me something like this

```
{"balance":94.5,"batch_id":309268453,"cost":0.5,"num_messages":1,"message":{"num_parts":1,"sender":"Audrey","content":"This is a test message from the PHP API script."},"receipt_url":"","custom":"","messages":[{"id":"1356746460","recipient":639000000000}],"status":"success"}
```

i can get the last string for the success messages. but what if the output is not success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what if the output is not success?

That's up to you to determine...

[Their documentation](http://api.txtlocal.com/docs/) states this:

> Every response will contain a "status" field, which can be either "success" or "failure". This field can be used to determine whether your request was successful.

Therefore, if you want to check it, you can do it [like so](https://eval.in/529144):

```
$result = json_decode($result);
if ($result->status == 'success') {
    echo 'It worked...';
} else {
    echo "It didn't work.";
}
```